# Android set screen overlay

Tags: android, layout, overlay

I have a big xml file that describes a lot of data such as image files, text, video files..etc to load on screen. I don't want to use `ScrollView`, I want to load each page to fit the screen and overlay the remaining data on the next page and page after that and so forth.

I was wondering if there was such a thing as page overlay for a linear layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using ViewFlipper in your xml file.

Comment: I am using a ViewFlipper to flip between layouts/pages however I am trying to find out how to overflow data that is at the end of the screen so that it goes on the next layout/page